# Creating an ArrayList of paths for all application's private images

Tags: android, android-camera, android-gallery

I need some help on how to access external storage to create an ArrayList of all of my application's private images.

In my application, I am able to take a photo using the camera and display that image right away using the following code:

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment {
public static String TAG = "Camera Fragment";

private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private Bitmap mImage;
private Uri mImageUri;
private ImageView mImageView;

public CameraFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);
    Button cameraButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_camera);
    mImageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.results);

    cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            takePhoto(v);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

private void takePhoto(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                                                                System.currentTimeMillis() + "_pic.jpg");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
    mImageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = mImageUri;
            ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
            contentResolver.notifyChange(selectedImage, null);

            try {
                mImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, selectedImage);
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImage);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), selectedImage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                galleryAddPic(selectedImage);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void galleryAddPic(Uri selectedImage) {
    Log.v(TAG, "adding image to gallery");
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(selectedImage);
    getActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

Now, I would like to display all images captured by this application on another activity. I have this POJO model to store the images when they are pulled out:

```
public class ImageItem {
private Bitmap image;
private String title;

public ImageItem(Bitmap image, String title) {
    super();
    this.image = image;
    this.title = title;
}

public Bitmap getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
```

}

I would like to make an `ArrayList<ImageItem>` using my images in external storage that I can then pass to my `GridViewAdapter`, but I don't know where to start.

Here is my `GridViewAdapter` for reference:

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private int mLayoutResourceId;
private ArrayList mData = new ArrayList();

public GridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    mLayoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    mContext = context;
    mData = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    ImageItem item = (ImageItem) mData.get(position);
    holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
    return row;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView imageTitle;
    ImageView image;
}
```

Comment: Are you thinking about holding all the bitmaps in memory? That can get very expensive. Perhaps do on demand loading or only hold thumbnail.

Comment: Eventually no.  I will only display images based on certain conditions. At this point I am lost on how to even gather these images.

Comment: You mean to load them into memory? Something like parse the directory where you saved them for the list of file, and then read the file into memory and then add to a list (for the adapter)?

Comment: When you put it that way, that doesn't sound very efficient.  What is the typical way for an Android app to retain a link to images it has taken?  Should I save the path  to them in the SQLlite database?

Comment: Typically you generate thumbnail, and have an array of reference/path to those thumbnail. Your adapter can load the thumb on demand as the item about to come into view. The grid view example does exactly this.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: They are using images that they added.  I would like to use images added by my application using the camera.  I am having trouble figuring out how to access those images.

Comment: Same idea. So instead of setImageResource to a resource id. You would be loading it by decoding a bitmap from file path (of list of file paths)

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

Comment: Yeah... So I guess I need to be storing these paths somewhere as I am making them.  I had just assumed(hoped) there was a way to get all images already taken.